# How to pass parameter into executeSQLScript in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to run SQL query in MATLAB.

I have a very long SQL. Initially I am using `data = fetch(conn, sql_query);` method. However, for this approach, I need add a lot of escape characters `'`.

So I am think about using `executeSQLScript`.

Here is a simplified version of my `query.sql`:

```
select
    t.id,
    t.voltage
from postgresql.public.motor as t
where
    t.id = uuid '126db7a1-e01f-494d-b034-11f2b20949cb';
```

Here is my MATLAB code:

```
conn = database('my-trino', 'username', 'passw0rd');

sql_file = 'query.sql';
res = executeSQLScript(conn, sql_file);
data = res.Data;
```

You can see I hard code `'126db7a1-e01f-494d-b034-11f2b20949cb'` in the SQL file. I hope to pass it as a paramter.

I read the `executeSQLScript` [document](https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database.odbc.connection.executesqlscript.html), it has two syntax:

```
results = executeSQLScript(conn,scriptfile)
results = executeSQLScript(conn,scriptfile,Name,Value)
```

However, the second one

> results = executeSQLScript(conn,scriptfile,Name,Value) specifies additional options using one or more name-value pair arguments. For example, 'DataReturnFormat','cellarray' stores the results of an executed SQL statement as a cell array. The results are stored in the Data field of the structure array.

It seems it allows me to provide options to change the behavior of `executeSQLScript`, but not how to pass parameter.

Just wonder is there a way to pass it as a parameter or other approaches? Thanks!